# How to render partial views inside tab in express JS?

Tags: node.js, express, tabs, handlebars.js

I want to know how to render partial views inside tab panel. My route starts with index page using below code:

```
var express = require('express')
  , router = express.Router()
  , index = require('../models/index')

router.use('/users', require('./api/users'))

/*GET home page*/
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
  index.all(function(err, gridData) {
    res.locals.gridData = JSON.stringify(gridData.details); 
    res.render('index');
  });
});
```

and my index page is below:

```
<div id="MainTab">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Tab1">Tab1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tab2">Tab2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Tab3">Tab3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Tab1">
        {{> Tab1 }}
    </div>
    <div id="Tab2">
        {{> Tab2 }}
    </div>  
    <div id="Lamination">
        {{> Tab3 }}
    </div>
</div>
```

and below are my partial pages with handlebars:

```
Tab1.hbs: <div id='Tab1_Content'>{{{gridData}}}</div>
Tab2.hbs: <div id='Tab2_Content'>Testing Tab2</div>
Tab3.hbs: <div id='Tab3_Content'>Testing Tab3</div>
```

Initially i will send data only to the Tab1. If i do like this, content inside the partial views of Tab2 and Tab3 is going out form the body content. Content of the remaining tabs should be load when clicking its respective tab headers. Please suggest me to load these partial views correctly inside the tab.

Comment: what does "../models/index" exports?